# Storage not properly linking in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So consider the following config:

```
    'registry_logo' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root' => storage_path('app/public/registry_logo/'),
        'url' => env('APP_URL').'/storage',
        'visibility' => 'public',
    ],
```

**Pretty basic, yes I have already ran `php artisan storage:link`**

So now how do I store the logo that gets uploaded?

```
public function uploadLogo(UploadedFile $file, RegistrySettings $settings): void {
    $path = $file->store('registry_logo');

    $settings->registry_logo = $path;

    $settings->save();
}
```

This lives inside a service and the first argument is `$request->registry_logo` which is a file (a mandatory one - so we can assume its not null).

When the logo is uploaded the link thats generated is: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/registry_logo/iuKceIG6XC5b8P5YLh3zMRMWbqGaZikaRP6sMWew.png`

So this seems fine, I fetch this via: `Storage::disk('registry_logo')->url($registrySettings->registry_logo)])`

Accept its not fine, lets look at two images:

[image]

As you can see there is no registry_logo folder in the linked storage, which makes no sense because:

[image]

It's there in storage. So whats going on? Why is it in the storage, but not linked properly? I have cleared the cache numerous times but when uploading it wont create the registry_logo link in the first image.

Sometimes, oddly enough, it will create the registry_logo folder but with nothing in it. Did I screw up the config? I am storing it properly, I know laravel likes the `$request->file('file')->store('disk_name')` but this way also works to upload a file, its just not linking properly and I am  wondering is that me - probably, but where could I look?

**Thoughts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter is the path to upload in the disk.

> Call the store method with the path at which you wish to store the uploaded file:

You simply have to specify the disk that you want to store to in your second parameter.

```php
$path = $file->store('', 'registry_logo');
```

Or you could do:

```php
$path = Storage::disk('registry_logo')->putFile($file);
```

For more information: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#file-uploads